# Adding a 'Controller' class to my MVC based Sencha Touch project

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have created a MVC SenchaTouch project.
I have created a sample application where the user will enter the username and password and send it to the web service.

The username, and password fields are suppose to be in the 'VIEW', and the 'sending it to the web service' functionality should be in the 'CONTROLLER'.

In my program, the sending to the web service part is also there in the 'VIEW', so can someone please help me edit my code, so that i could have the 'send to the web service' functionality in the 'CONTROLLER'

Here's the code

```
Ext.define('TU.view.Contact',{
           extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
           xtype:'contactform',

           config: {

           title:'Contact',
           iconCls:'user',

           url:'http://somesite.com/contact.php',
           items: [
           {
                   xtype:'fieldset',
                   title:'User Login',

                   items:[
                          {
                          xtype:'textfield',
                          name:'name',
                          label:'Name'
                          },
                          {
                          xtype:'passwordfield',
                          name:'password',
                          label:'Password'
                          }
                          ]
           },
           {
                   xtype:'button',
                   text:'Send',
                   ui:'confirm',
                   padding:5,
                   handler:function(){
                   this.up(contactform).submit();

                   }
           }
           ]



           }




           });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, set the `id` property for your button.

```
 xtype:'button',
 id:'submitBtn',
 text:'Send'
 .....
 .....
```

In the controller class,

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs : {
            submitBtn: '#submitBtn'
        },

        control : {
            submitBtn: {
                tap: 'submitData'
            }
        },
    },

    submitData: function() {
             var form = Ext.getCmp('form-id');

             // Get username and password fields ...
             var formvalues = form.getValues();

             // Web Service code goes here ..
             Ext.Ajax.request({
                 params: formvalues,                     
                 url:'http://_servername_.com/app/insert.php'

                 success : function() {
                       Ext.Msg.alert('Success','Username and password successfully entered');
                 }

                 failure : function() {
                       Ext.Msg.alert('Failure','Error while adding data');
                 }
             });        
    }
});
```

**NOTE :** `insert.php` will be the server side code ( just an e.g) that will make a connection with your database and enter the values in it.

Comment: 1.) Do i have to get rid of `handler:function(){
                   this.up(contactform).submit();

                   }` line of code from `contactView.js` ? 2.) Is `MyApp.controller.Main` the name of the Controller class ? (my controller class is called `myController.js`) ?

Comment: 1) Since you need to call the web service code from the controller file, you can safely get rid of that handler function from the view....
2)`Main.js` is the name of my controller file. Just change it to `'myController.js'` for your code.

FYI, `MyApp` is the sample name that I gave for my application

Comment: I added an alert statement `alert('came here');` before the comment `// Web Service code goes here ..`, and that line didn't get executed. Any clues ?

Comment: Also make sure you'r including this controller file in the `controller:['myController.js']` in the `app.js` file ..

Comment: There are no warnings, in the console, i have added `controller:['LoginController'],` in the app.js file. What is the `#` in the `submitBtn: '#submitBtn'` code ?

Comment: Read this for more information .. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/controllers